# How to auto submit a form when 10 characters is entered in the input text field

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a simple file form. How do I make it submit automatically when 10 characters is entered I don't want the use the Submit button.

Answer (score 2):

The <form> element in javascript has a submit() function.

Here is an example without using jQuery:

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" value="" placeholder="type here!" />
</form>
```

JS (no jquery) https://jsfiddle.net/m9deaxk5/

```
var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
text.onkeyup = function() {
    if( text.value.length == 10 ) {
        form.submit();
  }
}
```

JS (with jQuery) https://jsfiddle.net/m9deaxk5/2/

```
var text = $("#mytext");
var form = $("#myform");
text.bind("change keyup", function() {
    if( $(this).val().length == 10 )
        $("#myform").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Just change ".input-field" to the target field name, class or id and "form" to the target form name, class or id.

```
$('.input-field').change(function() {
    var value = $('.input-field').val();
    if(value.length >= 10) {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.